# Wrapping css grid and streching one grid item to take up all empty columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the last grid item fill all empty columns in a css grid that has auto-fit for wrapping items.

I've read [Expand a div to fill the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-a-div-to-fill-the-remaining-width) and [Make last element take remaining width with wrapping (and with IE9 support)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681218/make-last-element-take-remaining-width-with-wrapping-and-with-ie9-support), but they don't answer the case of the dynamically wrapping grid that is here the important part since they are made for `float` and `display: block`.

So for example if the grid-item is wrapped in a new line i want it to stretch for taking all the empty space.

If you look at the code then the div number 7 should always take all the empty space in the row. I've managed to hack something which dosen't seem robust enough, using `100vw` is there a better way?

For the following example: resize the window to see the items wrap into the next lines:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid-element {
  background-color: deepPink;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.grid-element:last-of-type {
  /*width: 100vw;*/ /* Is there a better way? */
}

body {
  padding: 2em;
}

hr {
  margin: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-element">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    7
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really possible with CSS-Grid, you need flexbox

Comment: Agree with above, but here's the link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-properties

Comment: Can you show the flex answer please?

Comment: Unfortunately the question is closed although it is **NO** duplicate since the linked question doesn't answer the case for wrapping items. But every try of mine to reopen a wrong closed question wasn't successful...

Comment: @biberman if you think a question was closed incorrectly, post it to [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Complaining in comments does not reopen questions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will try it...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be achieved with `display: flex`. In addition, it is necessary to use `flex-grow` property.

[As mdn says about `flex-grow`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)

> The flex-grow CSS property sets the flex grow factor of a flex item's
> main size

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-element {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 120px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-element">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      7
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This answers not the question since the OP wanted auto-fit for wrapping items.

Comment: @biberman it autofits to the container. Author can set desirable `width` and it will autofit to container.

Comment: But it doesn't wrap like the reproducable example in the question. @StepUp try it: open it in full page mode and resize the window...

Comment: @biberman I just edited width and it looks like it wraps, please, see my updated answer

Comment: Aw: @StepUp yes, you are right but all items in your last row grow and not just div number 7...

Comment: @biberman  try to play with resizing in your browser and it can be seen that the last item can take the full row

Comment: I did and did again after your comment - it's still the same: when you shrink the window so that div number 6 comes to the second line both last divs stretch - please try again...